# Get news feed using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following to make my requests to Facebook

```
$facebook->api('/feed', 
array(
  'access_token' => $_SESSION['fb_access_token'],
));
```

However, I want to get the news feed of the user.

Not to be confused: I do not want the feed of a certain user, much less of a given page.

I want the News Feed/Feed Stream the user views when accessing Facebook, one that contains the posts of your friends, etc.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an API call to `/me/home` or `/user_id/home` where `user_id` is the current session user.

You are also using the old PHP SDK

```
/* PHP SDK v4.0.0 */
/* make the API call */
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'GET',
  '/me/home'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */
```

Reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/home

**UPDATE**:
The latest Graph API [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/home) suggests the following:
As of October 6th, 2015, this endpoint is no longer available. Please consider using the /user-id/feed edge instead.

This effectively means we cannot access the user news feed provided by Facebook but will have to rely on [/user-id/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is `me/home`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/home

> The posts that a person sees in their Facebook News Feed.

Answer (score -3):

Getting all recent notifications including read via Graph API, call:

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/notifications?include_read=true
```